# C#, Can't load multiple instances of a plugin

Tags: c#, plugins, instances

I have a single plugin, that takes value for an input and returns the result. I'm loading it like this:

```
public void load_modules()
{
    string path = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0].FullyQualifiedName;
    string pluginDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(path) + "\\Modules";

    foreach (string s in Directory.GetFiles(pluginDir, "*.dll"))
    {
        Type[] pluginTypes = Assembly.LoadFile(s).GetTypes();

        foreach (Type t in pluginTypes)
        {
            if (t.ToString().Contains("Main"))
            {
                MY_API module = Activator.CreateInstance(t) as MY_API;


                GLOBAL_VARIABLES.MODULES.Add(module);

                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the code I'm using to execute plugin:

```
 List<MY_API> plugin_instances  = new List<MY_API>(); // define container of the instances
 for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
     plugin_instances.add(GLOBAL_VARIABLES.MODULES[0]); // loaded module from load_modules()

     MessageBox.show(plugin_instances.exec(i)); // execute plugin
 }
```

And I have a timer to monitor to minor status of the first loaded module.

```
label1.text = GLOBAL_VARIABLES.MODULES[0].getStatus();
```

The getStatus() function displays what variable is passed to plugin's exec() function.

**The problem is** 
I **didn't** execute the *GLOBAL_VARIABLES.MODULES[0]*, I only used it to make copies off of it. I executed all plugins in *plugin_instances* list, which should contain 10 copies of *GLOBAL_VARIABLES.MODULES[0]*.

To my surprise GLOBAL_VARIABLES.MODULES[0] gets executed, even though it shouldn't, I can see that on label1. Instead of executing 10 instances of my plugin, the GLOBAL_VARIABLES.MODULES[0] gets executed 10 times.

Seems like plugin_instances.exec(i) acts like a reference to GLOBAL_VARIABLES.MODULES[0], instead of individual copy of GLOBAL_VARIABLES.MODULES[0].

How can I get each instance individual, not as reference? Thanks!

Comment: where are you making the copy of `GLOBAL_VARIABLES.MODULES[0]` ? All your current code is showing is that you add the same instance to the list 10 times, so of course that instance is executed 10 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to reflect question modification:

You need to create a new instance of the module type for each one that you want to execute. You may need to clean the following code up, but it gives you the idea:

```
 plugin_instances.add(Activator.CreateInstance(GLOBAL_VARIABLES.MODULES[0].GetType()));
```

Comment: There is only one module loaded from the directory, therefor I use [0] instead of [i]. GLOBAL_VARIABLES.MODULES contains only one module from which I need to make 10 copies

Comment: I understand now: you need to create a new instance of the plugin module on each pass through the loop, not just reuse the existing one. I have updated the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to make a copy and the type you want to make a copy of has a parameter-less constructor you could just dynamically create a new instance:

```
 var moduleType = GLOBAL_VARIABLES.MODULES[0].GetType();
 for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
 {
     plugin_instances.add((MY_API)Activator.CreateInstance(moduleType));
```